# Adding images Asynchronously - ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, asihttprequest

I am using `ASIHTTPRequest`. I have the following issues while using `ASIHTTPRequest`.

1.) I need to add images to `UITableView` (for each cell) `asynchronously`. How can i do this ?

2.) I need to add an image to a `UIViewController` `Asynchronously`. (Not to a cell, but just on the `UIImageView`, which is on a `UIViewController`).

Can someone please help me with some sample code, Example or a Tutorial to start with?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How? UITableViewCell with UIImageView asynchronously loaded via ASINetworkQueue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380791/how-uitableviewcell-with-uiimageview-asynchronously-loaded-via-asinetworkqueue)

Answer (score 6):

No need to introduce a dependency to a whole framework such as `ASIHTTPRequest` just to download one image, when you can do it a few easy lines of code using GCD:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSData *imageDate = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        avatar.image = image;
    });
});
```

This is asynchronous and all the goodness. But in a few lines of code you can write, understand, bug-fix, extend and maintain yourself.

But in case you are bent on using `ASIHTTPRequest` I suggest using this excellent project  [**Here**](https://github.com/akosma/async-uitableview/) is a sample code to have a guide line and [**a brief description.**](http://kosmaczewski.net/asynchronous-loading-of-images-in-a-uitableview/)

One other way is that you can use the asynchronous image view instead of the default image view. check tutorial [Here](http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/) and also [How? UITableViewCell with UIImageView asynchronously loaded via ASINetworkQueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380791/how-uitableviewcell-with-uiimageview-asynchronously-loaded-via-asinetworkqueue)

Comment: Hey, is it OK to use multiple libraries in a project ? As in  async-uitableview and ASIHTTPRequest  ? and what is so special about using another library when you can do it in only ASIHTTPRequest  ? (I am a beginner) and also the brief description link ends up in a 404, could you kindly re-link it

Comment: yes you can use multiple libraries in same project. `async-uitableview` is an abstraction on top of `ASIHTTPRequest. `async-uitableview` specifically addresses asynchronous download of images in tableview.

Comment: @Srikar dispatch_async - I saw it first time today and used it. Thanks for this info. It looks good method to use.

Answer (score 0):

Basically ([see example page with all the correct syntax](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)) what you do is

- Create a request.
- Set yourself as a delegate for when it's complete.
- Start the request.

In -(void)requestFinished: you add the image to your TableView as you would in normal code.

Comment: I am already using `requestFinished` to get other data to be displayed in the tableview. and this data that i will be receiving will have a link to the image i wish to download. So how can i use `requestFinished` again to download the image ?

Comment: When requestFinished is called, the file is already downloaded, and you just use NSData *responseData = [request responseData]; to get to the actual downloaded content.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it's exactly what you are looking for, but check out the [lazy image loading example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) from apple. But they use NSURLConnection.

Hope it helps